# Rest Client vs Code extension Problem with Form Data

Tags: http, server, rest-client

I passed a form data using the Rest client. But it always shows an empty object in vs code console log.

This is the request.

```
POST {{Host_LOCAL}}/support/testFormData
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"; name="email"
Content-Type: text/plain

{
    "username": "John Doe",
    "email": "123456"                

}


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Where is the problem?
Thanks in advance